# Backup returned keys from reg query to file in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I want to be able to export key-values of registry keys as returned by `reg query`.
I'm trying to write a script to find registration for a particular `dll` and then write all keys to a `backup file`, before trying to achieve uninstall by deleting the keys. Here's what I could come up with so far:

```
@echo off

reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes /s /f %1 2>&1 >NUL
if errorlevel 1 goto DLL_MISSING

for /f "tokens=1,1" %%a in ('reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes /s /f %1 2^>NUL ^| findstr /I "^HKEY_"') do (
echo %%a
REG export %%a Backup.REG
)
goto :DLL_FOUND

:DLL_MISSING
echo Assembly not found.
goto :eof
:DLL_FOUND
echo Assembly found.
```

Right now `reg export` prompts to overwrite file, which I want append instead.
How can I achieve the same?
Also, please do suggest if there is some better way to automate uninstall `duplicate(?)` installs as installed by 'regasm'.
I could prefer batch-file based solution instead of `Powershell` or something else. Thanks!

Comment: `Regsvr32 /u dllname` do it from the correct bitness cmd prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reg.exe` does not support appending/combining of several exported keys. The easiest workaround seems to be to output each key's data into a separate file, and then merge these into a single file afterwards. Note that you need to make sure that the output key file is not picked up by the `FOR` loop, which I ensured by simply placing the combined key file in a subfolder called `target`.

```
@ECHO OFF   

MKDIR target
ECHO Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 > target\combined.reg

FOR %%G IN (*.reg) DO (
    TYPE "%%G" | FINDSTR /V "Windows Registry Editor" >> target\combined.reg
    DEL "%%G"
)
```

Comment: It did occur to me, to write out files in tempfile, and use findstr, like constructs to merge respective entities to a common file. I'll post a solution once I write one. I've difficulty in findstr constructs. The inclusion in sub-directory is cool. Thanks again!:)

Comment: @user2338150: [`FINDSTR` is a beast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman) best avoided, however in this case, the filtering required (skipping the header line) is sufficiently simple for `FINDSTR` to cope.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wrote:
It's basically similar to what was proposed by @zb226.

```
@echo off

reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes /s /f %1 2>&1 >NUL
if errorlevel 1 goto DLL_MISSING

ECHO Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 > backup.reg

for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ('reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes /s /f "%1" 2^>NUL ^| findstr /I "^HKEY_"') do (
echo Deleting : %%a
reg export %%a bkp_tmp.reg /y >nul 2>&1
type bkp_tmp.reg | FINDSTR /V "Windows Registry Editor" >> backup.reg
reg delete %%a /f >nul 2>&1
)
del /f bkp_tmp.reg
goto :DLL_FOUND

:DLL_MISSING
echo Assembly not found.
goto :eof
:DLL_FOUND
echo Assembly found.
```

It's ugly, as there definitely are key repetitions, but works for now.
The same goes for `reg delete` operations. It's manageable for now, but definitely there could be a better solution.